# Is it possible to use both S3 Query String Authentication and HTTP caching?

Tags: authentication, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, http-caching

I have the following requirements for a (Rails) web application that uses S3/Cloudfront for image storage:

1. A user may only see an image if they are logged in. If the user sends an image URL to a friend, it will not work.
2. If a user has seen an image, it should be cached by their browser, so they don't have to download it again.

…

- Requirement 1 can solved with S3's Query String Authentication (QSA)
  (e.g. with 30 second expiry).
- Requirement 2 can be solved using HTTP
  caching.

**Is it possible to use them both together?**

The challenge I'm facing is that QSA effectively changes the URL of the image after expiry, even though a perfectly good copy may reside in the browser cache.

Comment: What if user and friend are working behind a proxy that caches the image?  - The problem I see is that the if you find a solution, and it allows a proxy server to cache that image at the same time, then anybody with that url behind the proxy can also access it.